# sendMessage with callback throws error in Chrome app

Tags: sendmessage, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to send message from content to background script within my Chrome app.

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message)
    sendResponse("hey man!");
});

// content.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("hello world!", function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

When i call `sendMessage` in content with callback specified (as described in code above), it end up with this error:

```
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

A Listener is not fired up, however, the callback is (with undefined response). When i omit the callback from sendMessage arguments (so only a message is passed), listener is fired up as expected.

I just can't figure out how to set up callback function to work. Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the samples? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/messaging/app1/index.js. Confirm that works, then modify it to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Code in the question worked for me when I added those two functions to the [window-state](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/window-state) sample, Chrome 30.0.1599.22.